# How to resample a dataframe by dropping every second row ( dropping every 30min measurements)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time series of measurements DataFrame that is time stamped every 30min (yyyy/mm/dd 00:30:00, yyyy/mm/dd 01:00:00 ect..), I just want to do a simple resampling by dropping the half hourly measurements and keep only the hourly measurements which could be done by dropping every second row. Any advise on how to do this.

Comment: You can do `df.iloc[::2]` but why lose them, you can set the index to that column and call `df.resample('1h')`

Comment: Hi Ed, df.resample('1h') apply a mean() by default that I don't want, I just want the hourly row data. In python 3.5, the .resample is deferred and .resample(....).mean() must be used instead.

Comment: Thanks anyway .loc[::2] does the job - simple and effective!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To drop every other row, keeping the first, use `df.iloc[::2]`.

To drop every other row, starting with the second, use `df.iloc[1::2]`.

---

Or, since the time series, `ts`, has a DatetimeIndex, you could use `ts.index.minute == 0` to select rows whose minutes equal 0:

```
In [146]: ts = pd.Series(1, index=pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=10, freq='30T'))

In [147]: ts
Out[147]: 
2000-01-01 00:00:00    1
2000-01-01 00:30:00    1
2000-01-01 01:00:00    1
2000-01-01 01:30:00    1
2000-01-01 02:00:00    1
2000-01-01 02:30:00    1
2000-01-01 03:00:00    1
2000-01-01 03:30:00    1
2000-01-01 04:00:00    1
2000-01-01 04:30:00    1
Freq: 30T, dtype: int64

In [148]: ts.loc[ts.index.minute == 0]
Out[148]: 
2000-01-01 00:00:00    1
2000-01-01 01:00:00    1
2000-01-01 02:00:00    1
2000-01-01 03:00:00    1
2000-01-01 04:00:00    1
Freq: 60T, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Must better option because it does not require having the DataFrame ordered - Thanks for that!!